# How does item xp work?

Tags: tribes-ascend

From the "Accelerate" patch notes:

> The system for upgrading weapons has been modified. Players will now
>   automatically receive weapon upgrades as they play a particular
>   weapon, without having to spend XP on the upgrade (allowing you to
>   save your XP for other items). A progress bar on the weapon’s menu
>   page will provide information as to when the next automatic upgrade
>   occurs. If you are impatient and have excess XP, an option is still
>   provided to immediately master an item using XP. Note that previously
>   purchased upgrades are still owned.

This affects primary weapons, secondary weapons, belt items, packs, armor, and maybe perks too (I don't have any yet so I can't confirm).

**What does a player do to accumulate item xp?**  Is it as simple as including the item in a loadout and playing a match or do I have to use the item in some way?

**At what rate is this xp accumulated?  Can I do anything to influence that?**

Speculation:

- Does holding/firing/damaging with a weapon matter?
- Does throwing/damaging with a grenade matter?
- Does skiing/jetting/getting damaged with an armor matter?
- Do activatable packs need to be active to get xp?
- Do passive packs need to be functioning to get xp?  Health/energy regen packs don't do anything when you're full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played two matches as a soldier and recorded some of the item xp gain.

The first match awarded 690 base + 192 bonus.  100% of the match was played as soldier.

- armor went from 2075 to 2957
- grenade went from 1975 to 2857 (not used at all)
- primary weapon went from 1975 to 2857 (used extensively)

So it seems that xp that is earned for a match is additionally applied to each item in the loadout used for the match.  **There is no course of action which increases item xp reward** other than those which increase the main xp reward (by playing more minutes, winning, placing high on the scoreboard, being a vip, buying a booster).

---

The second match awarded 524 base + 142 bonus.  10 minutes of the ~15 minute match was played as soldier.

- grenade went from 2857 to 3277 (not used at all).

About 2/3 of the xp was awarded to the soldier, which played 2/3 of the match.